# Create dataframe with all unique combinations given a set of constraints

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I need to create a dataframe with all the possible unique combinations of n number of original arrays given a couple constraints. I want to be able to do this without filtering down the initial dataframe due to memory constraints.

There will be two types of original input arrays. Either they will have boolean values of just True and False, or they will have a variable amount of float values.

The additional tricky layer is that any row should only have one non zero float value, the other float values must be a 0.

#### Example input:

```py
inputs = {
    "a": [True, False],
    "b": [True, False],
    "c": [0.0, 0.1, 0.2],
    "d": [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
}

bool_inputs = {"a", "b"}
float_inputs = {"c", "d"}
```

#### Example Output:

```
        a      b    c    d
0    True   True  0.0  0.0
1    True  False  0.0  0.0
2   False   True  0.0  0.0
3   False  False  0.0  0.0
4    True   True  0.1  0.0
5    True  False  0.1  0.0
6   False   True  0.1  0.0
7   False  False  0.1  0.0
8    True   True  0.2  0.0
9    True  False  0.2  0.0
10  False   True  0.2  0.0
11  False  False  0.2  0.0
12   True   True  0.0  0.1
13   True  False  0.0  0.1
14  False   True  0.0  0.1
15  False  False  0.0  0.1
16   True   True  0.0  0.2
17   True  False  0.0  0.2
18  False   True  0.0  0.2
19  False  False  0.0  0.2
20   True   True  0.0  0.3
21   True  False  0.0  0.3
22  False   True  0.0  0.3
23  False  False  0.0  0.3
```

I have been able to do this by filtering the data afterwards with the below solution, but I am wanting to not have any filtering. A bonus would also be not having to fix the column types

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


input_arrays = list(inputs.values())
results = np.array(np.meshgrid(*input_arrays)).T.reshape(-1, len(inputs))

df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=list(inputs.keys()))

df[list(bool_inputs)] = df[list(bool_inputs)].astype(bool)
df = df[~(df[list(float_inputs)] > 0).all(axis=1)]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key to not having to filter the float columns is making a block diagonal matrix.  Everything else here is just `.join(..., how = 'cross')`

```
from scipy.linalg import block_diag
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

inputs = {
    "a": [True, False],
    "b": [True, False],
    "c": [0.0, 0.1, 0.2],
    "d": [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
}

bool_inputs = {"a", "b"}
float_inputs = {"c", "d"}

num = block_diag(*[np.array(inputs[k])[None, np.flatnonzero(inputs[k])] for k in float_inputs]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = float_inputs, data = num)


for k in bool_inputs:
    df = df.join(pd.DataFrame(columns = [k], data = inputs[k]), how = 'cross')
    
df = df.reindex(sorted(df.columns), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
        a      b    c    d
0    True   True  0.1  0.0
1   False   True  0.1  0.0
2    True  False  0.1  0.0
3   False  False  0.1  0.0
4    True   True  0.2  0.0
5   False   True  0.2  0.0
6    True  False  0.2  0.0
7   False  False  0.2  0.0
8    True   True  0.0  0.1
9   False   True  0.0  0.1
10   True  False  0.0  0.1
11  False  False  0.0  0.1
12   True   True  0.0  0.2
13  False   True  0.0  0.2
14   True  False  0.0  0.2
15  False  False  0.0  0.2
16   True   True  0.0  0.3
17  False   True  0.0  0.3
18   True  False  0.0  0.3
19  False  False  0.0  0.3
```

EDIT: I assumed that "Only one non-zero float column" was strict, otherwise replace:

```
num = block_diag(*[np.array(inputs[k])[None, np.flatnonzero(inputs[k])] for k in float_inputs]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = float_inputs, data = num)
```

with:

```
num = block_diag(*np.array(inputs[k])[None, np.flatnonzero(inputs[k])] for k in float_inputs]).T
num = np.r_[np.zeros_like(num)[[0], :], num]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = float_inputs, data = num)
```

Comment: Awesome, this is a great solution and simple!

Comment: @Nick, fixed that issue, thanks

Comment: @DanielF cool. I'll delete the comment

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to see a way around filtering, but you can probably improve performance by pre-filtering, using [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate your data:

```
import itertools

inputs = {
    "a": [True, False],
    "b": [True, False],
    "c": [0.0, 0.1, 0.2],
    "d": [0.0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3],
}

bool_inputs = {"a", "b"}
float_inputs = {"c", "d"}

columns = list(inputs)
float_indexes = [columns.index(f) for f in float_inputs]

data = (t for t in itertools.product(*inputs.values()) if sum(t[i] > 0 for i in float_indexes) <= 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
        a      b    c    d
0    True   True  0.0  0.0
1    True   True  0.0  0.1
2    True   True  0.0  0.2
3    True   True  0.0  0.3
4    True   True  0.1  0.0
5    True   True  0.2  0.0
6    True  False  0.0  0.0
7    True  False  0.0  0.1
8    True  False  0.0  0.2
9    True  False  0.0  0.3
10   True  False  0.1  0.0
11   True  False  0.2  0.0
12  False   True  0.0  0.0
13  False   True  0.0  0.1
14  False   True  0.0  0.2
15  False   True  0.0  0.3
16  False   True  0.1  0.0
17  False   True  0.2  0.0
18  False  False  0.0  0.0
19  False  False  0.0  0.1
20  False  False  0.0  0.2
21  False  False  0.0  0.3
22  False  False  0.1  0.0
23  False  False  0.2  0.0
```

If you want the data sorted in a particular order, you can change the order of columns going into `itertools.product`. For example, to get the same output as in your question, you can use:

```
columns = list(inputs)
col_order = ['d', 'c', 'a', 'b']
float_indexes = [col_order.index(f) for f in float_inputs]

data = (t for t in itertools.product(*[inputs[k] for k in col_order]) if sum(t[i] > 0 for i in float_indexes) <= 1)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_order).reset_index(drop=True)[columns]
```

Output:

```
        a      b    c    d
0    True   True  0.0  0.0
1    True  False  0.0  0.0
2   False   True  0.0  0.0
3   False  False  0.0  0.0
4    True   True  0.1  0.0
5    True  False  0.1  0.0
6   False   True  0.1  0.0
7   False  False  0.1  0.0
8    True   True  0.2  0.0
9    True  False  0.2  0.0
10  False   True  0.2  0.0
11  False  False  0.2  0.0
12   True   True  0.0  0.1
13   True  False  0.0  0.1
14  False   True  0.0  0.1
15  False  False  0.0  0.1
16   True   True  0.0  0.2
17   True  False  0.0  0.2
18  False   True  0.0  0.2
19  False  False  0.0  0.2
20   True   True  0.0  0.3
21   True  False  0.0  0.3
22  False   True  0.0  0.3
23  False  False  0.0  0.3
```

Comment: This helps with the memory problem, but unfortunately is a good bit slower than the original solution as the combinations increase

Comment: @TheOleGaffer it's likely most of that time is spent sorting. Please see my edit which explains how to get the ordering you desire without any sorting.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to create a floats dataframe, a bools dataframe, and merge them. To build the floats, iterate through the arrays and filter out the non matches. Doing this in numba (any low level option should work) should give you a decent speed up, while allowing you to maximise performance, where you are not filtering after, but before.

```py
# pip install numba
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

bools = [pd.Series(inputs[key],name=key) for key in bool_inputs]
floats = {key: np.array(inputs[key]) for key in float_inputs}

# precompute the floats dataframe size
counts=1
totals=1
for k, v in floats.items():
    counts *= np.count_nonzero(v)
    totals *= v.size
new_array_size = totals - counts
float_values = [value for _, value in floats.items()]
start, end = float_values
arr = np.empty((new_array_size, 2),dtype=float)

@nb.njit()
def build_floats_2d_array(start, end, arr):
    l1 = start.size
    l2 = end.size
    ind=0
    for num in range(l1):
        outer = start[num]
        for n in range(l2):
            inner = end[n]
            # this is where the prefiltering occurs
            if outer and inner:
                continue
            arr[ind,0]=outer
            arr[ind,1]=inner
            ind += 1
    return arr

floats_2d_array = build_floats_2d_array(start=start,end=end,arr=arr)
floats_df = pd.DataFrame(floats_2d_array, columns=list(floats))

# build the bools_df, which should be a cartesian
a,b=bools
bools_df = pd.merge(a,b, how='cross')

# create final dataframe, which is a cartesian of the new dfs:

(pd.merge(bools_df, floats_df,how='cross')
    # relevant only if the columns are not already sorted
   .sort_index(axis='columns')
)

        a      b    c    d
0    True   True  0.0  0.0
1    True   True  0.1  0.0
2    True   True  0.2  0.0
3    True   True  0.0  0.1
4    True   True  0.0  0.2
5    True   True  0.0  0.3
6   False   True  0.0  0.0
7   False   True  0.1  0.0
8   False   True  0.2  0.0
9   False   True  0.0  0.1
10  False   True  0.0  0.2
11  False   True  0.0  0.3
12   True  False  0.0  0.0
13   True  False  0.1  0.0
14   True  False  0.2  0.0
15   True  False  0.0  0.1
16   True  False  0.0  0.2
17   True  False  0.0  0.3
18  False  False  0.0  0.0
19  False  False  0.1  0.0
20  False  False  0.2  0.0
21  False  False  0.0  0.1
22  False  False  0.0  0.2
23  False  False  0.0  0.3
```

if you want to squeeze more performance, you could possibly shift the entire array creation into numba, and create the final dataframe after. Not sure if it is worth the effort though.